# Debug asp.net core mvc web application with live preview in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, web-applications, live-preview

I'm a web designer and I want to visualize the code changes in real time in VS Code, but for now I haven't been able to do that with this kind of asp.net core application.

The "Live Preview", "Live Server" and "Five Server" extension didn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, I don't know. Can anybody help me? Do you know if there is a specific way to do this?

[With "Five Server" appears the option to open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzRWi.png)

[But when it opens it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7fXD.png)

Comment: .cshtml files are not meant to be used like .html files. They are server side files that compile to classes that generate html. I suggest you use the dotnet cli in a new temporary project to see how mvc works: `dotnet new mvc`

Comment: If your asp.net-core startup includes `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`, you can save the `.cshtml` file, then immediately `F5` the browser side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion given by @Crowcoder.

> VS Code doesn't have built-in support for HTML preview but there are
> extensions available in the VS Code Marketplace. Open the Extensions
> view (Ctrl+Shift+X) and search on 'live preview' or 'html preview' to
> see a list of available HTML preview extensions.

With the help of extensions, you could preview HTML files but in your screenshots, we could see that you want to preview the `.cshtml` file. Which is not supported even if you use any extensions.

Reference: [Does VS Code have HTML preview?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_does-vs-code-have-html-preview)